# Unexpected cookie domain after injecting cooking script to WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I am initializing a WKWebView with a script that injects cookies. The script has the form:

```
document.cookie = 'mycookie=2bxxx962-b525-4afb-88de-ae4f12ecaxxxx;domain=stage.site.com;path=/;expires=Fri, 10 Apr 2020 21:32:50 GMT';
```

But, after I load a url and inspect the cookies, the cookie has a `domain=".stage.site.com"`

Does someone know why the dot is being added? This is causing problems downstream as I now have duplicate cookies.

Comment: What steps lead to duplicate cookies?

Comment: Cookie storage should not affect page behavior, so describe what unexpected behavior you observe, without digging cookie storage.

Comment: Leading dots in domain names come from earlier specifications. It should not cause problem. If it really cause, would you like to add an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

becuse your domain is has a subdomain. .site.com is default use browser isnt check subdomain if is begin with "."
it's should useful for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie